Nuxt3 i18n setup diffrent domains
I want to create an app which will have internalization using Nuxt 3 and @nuxtjs/i18n.
My plan is to have 2 locales for now.
So we have myappidea.fr (default locale French) and another locale as myappidea.com/de (Greman locale).
So both urls will run the same codebase which should use the locales based on url.
But dont want users to navigate and change locale between domains. For example if they are on french domain myappidea.fr, they should not be able to run myappidea.fr/de/page1 and return 404.
What is the best approach for this one?
I tried through docs to run this configuration on nuxt.config.ts


i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'fr',
        file: 'locales/fe.json',
        domain: 'https://someurlhere.fr/'
      },
      {
        code: 'de',
        file: 'locales/de.json',
        domain: 'https://someurlhere.com/de/'
      }
    ],
    differentDomains: true,
    defaultLocale: 'fr',
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false
  }



But it seems that is not working properly. I am able to visit myappidea.fr/de/page1, but I want this to be forbidden and /de/page1 to be accessible only from .com domain.
Also when I run into https://someurlhere.com/ I want it to load https://someurlhere.com/de as fist laod page-url.
Is it the config I have that is wrong or is my approach totally wrong?
